# Is the output really correct about the std::memory_order_relaxed's example in the C++ Concurrency in Action 2ed?

Tags: c++, concurrency

In the C++ Concurrency in Action 2ed book, there is an example, listing 5.6 that explains how `std::memory_order_relaxed` order behaves. The example's code is as below:

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
std::atomic<int> x(0),y(0),z(0); 
std::atomic<bool> go(false); 
unsigned const loop_count=10;
struct read_values
{
 int x,y,z;
};
read_values values1[loop_count];
read_values values2[loop_count];
read_values values3[loop_count];
read_values values4[loop_count];
read_values values5[loop_count];
void increment(std::atomic<int>* var_to_inc,read_values* values)
{
 while(!go) 
 std::this_thread::yield();
 for(unsigned i=0;i<loop_count;++i)
 {
 values[i].x=x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
 values[i].y=y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
 values[i].z=z.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
 var_to_inc->store(i+1,std::memory_order_relaxed); 
 std::this_thread::yield();
 }
}
void read_vals(read_values* values)
{
 while(!go) 
 std::this_thread::yield();
 for(unsigned i=0;i<loop_count;++i)
 {
 values[i].x=x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
 values[i].y=y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
 values[i].z=z.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
 std::this_thread::yield();
 }
}
void print(read_values* v)
{
 for(unsigned i=0;i<loop_count;++i)
 {
 if(i)
 std::cout<<",";
 std::cout<<"("<<v[i].x<<","<<v[i].y<<","<<v[i].z<<")";
 }
 std::cout<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
 std::thread t1(increment,&x,values1);
 std::thread t2(increment,&y,values2);
 std::thread t3(increment,&z,values3);
 std::thread t4(read_vals,values4);
 std::thread t5(read_vals,values5);
 go=true; 
 t5.join();
 t4.join();
 t3.join();
 t2.join();
 t1.join();
 print(values1); 
 print(values2);
 print(values3);
 print(values4);
 print(values5);
}
```

with the following one possible output:

```
(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(2,0,0),(3,0,0),(4,0,0),(5,7,0),(6,7,8),(7,9,8),(8,9,8),
(9,9,10)
(0,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,2,0),(1,3,5),(8,4,5),(8,5,5),(8,6,6),(8,7,9),(10,8,9),
(10,9,10)
(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,2),(0,0,3),(0,0,4),(0,0,5),(0,0,6),(0,0,7),(0,0,8),
(0,0,9)
(1,3,0),(2,3,0),(2,4,1),(3,6,4),(3,9,5),(5,10,6),(5,10,8),(5,10,10),
(9,10,10),(10,10,10)
(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(6,3,7),(6,5,7),(7,7,7),(7,8,7),(8,8,7),(8,8,9),
(8,8,9)
```

In the first thread, when x was updated to 5, the first thread saw the value of y that is 7.
In the second thread, when y was updated to 4, the second thread saw the value of x that is 8.

Because only the first thread has updated the same variable x ten times, the same as y, so there was no 'write reorder'. Therefore, when the first thread saw y was updated to 7 at the first time, the second thread could see the value of x was range 0-5. But when y was updated to 4, the second thread saw the value of x that is 8.

I can not understand why the output is correct, can someone explain it? thansks.

I tested the above exapmle on windows 10 with multiple CPUs, but I count not get the similar results.
After that, I also checked some papers about memory order, like [Shared memory consistency models](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/WRL-95-7.pdf), But there was no answer for me.
And I searched some time on Stack Overflow, there was no results related.